# Modify/Add to the code with the foreach loop below to only show the books within the price range selected

Tags: php

Im not sure how to 
 Modify/Add the code with the foreach loop below to only  show the books within 
 the price range selected. I want the under $20 books to only show under the $20 section. The same for under $50 and under $100.

```
<?php

    $books = array ();
    $books[0] = array();
        $books[0]['ISBN'] = "1234567890";
        $books[0]['Title'] = "PHP for Dummies";
        $books[0]['Price'] = "35.99";
    $books[1] = array();
        $books[1]['ISBN'] = "2345678901";
        $books[1]['Title'] = "SQL for Dummies";
        $books[1]['Price'] = "78.49";
    $books[2] = array();
        $books[2]['ISBN'] = "3456789012";
        $books[2]['Title'] = "Economics for Dummies";
        $books[2]['Price'] = "44.99";
    $books[3] = array();
        $books[3]['ISBN'] = "4567890123";
        $books[3]['Title'] = "History of Dummies";
        $books[3]['Price'] = "62.49";
    $books[4] = array();
        $books[4]['ISBN'] = "5678901234";
        $books[4]['Title'] = "Marketing for Dummies";
        $books[4]['Price'] = "52.49";
    $books[5] = array();
        $books[5]['ISBN'] = "6789012345";
        $books[5]['Title'] = "Gardening for Dummies";
        $books[5]['Price'] = "19.99";

    // function to generate the book list
    function listBook($maximum){
    global $books; // make $books array available inside the function

    echo "<table>\n
        <caption>Under $maximum</caption>
        <tr><th>Title</th><th>ISBN</th><th>Price</th></tr>\n
    ";

    //###############################
    // Try the script in its current form.  You will find that no matter what price range is chosen, all books are presented all the time.  It's not what we want.
    // Modify/Add to the code with the foreach loop below to only  show the books within the price range selected.
    //###############################
    foreach ($books as $book) {

            $title = $book['Title'];
            $ISBN = $book['ISBN'];
            $price = $book['Price'];


            echo "<tr><td>$title</td> <td>$ISBN</td> <td>$price</td></tr>\n";

        }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a simple [if](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php):

```
function listBook($maximum) {
  global $books; // make $books array available inside the function

  echo "<table>\n
    <caption>Under $maximum</caption>
    <tr><th>Title</th><th>ISBN</th><th>Price</th></tr>\n
";

  //###############################
  // Try the script in its current form.  You will find that no matter what price range is chosen, all books are presented all the time.  It's not what we want.
  // Modify/Add to the code with the foreach loop below to only  show the books within the price range selected.
  //###############################
  foreach ($books as $book) {
    $title = $book['Title'];
    $ISBN  = $book['ISBN'];
    $price = $book['Price'];
    if ($price <= $maximum) {
      echo "<tr><td>$title</td> <td>$ISBN</td> <td>$price</td></tr>\n";
    }
  }
  echo "</table>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this to wrap the echo statement that outputs the HTML in an IF statement. Say you have a variable that holds the selected price, then you would do this:

```
$selectedPrice = 20;
if($price <= $selectedPrice) {
   echo "<tr><td>$title</td> <td>$ISBN</td> <td>$price</td></tr>\n";
}
```

or, for a range between a high and low price

```
$highPrice = 100;
$lowPrice = 50
if($lowPrice <= $price && $price <= $selectedPrice) {
   echo "<tr><td>$title</td> <td>$ISBN</td> <td>$price</td></tr>\n";
}
```

Your example doesn't include how the price is collected however, although a likely mechanism would be either a select drop down or a couple of input boxes.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach loop:

```
foreach ($books as $book) {
        $title = $book['Title'];
        $ISBN = $book['ISBN'];
        $price = $book['Price'];

        if ((int) $price > round($maximum, 2))
            continue;

        echo "<tr><td>$title</td> <td>$ISBN</td> <td>$price</td></tr>\n";

    }
echo "</table>";
}
```